# Solving $|\frac{x+1}{x}|< 1$

Tags: absolute-value

I need some help/suggestions solving the following math problem. I don't know how to continue from step 2. Find x.

1.) $\displaystyle\left|\frac{x+1}{x}\right|< 1$

2.) $\displaystyle\frac{|x+1|}{|x|} < 1$

Comment: But... what is the problem to solve?

Comment: $|a|<b <=> -b < a < b $, then solve for the two separate inequality($a<b$ and $-b<a$) and take the intersection of the solutions.

Comment: Multiply with $|x|$, to get $|x + 1| < |x|$. Now draw some pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{x+1}{x}\right|< 1$$

$$\left|1 + \frac{1}{x}\right|<1\\-1<1 + \frac{1}{x}<1\\ -2<\frac{1}{x}<0 \\\left(\frac{1}{x} >-2\right) \wedge \left(\frac{1}{x}<0\right)$$

Dismiss $\displaystyle x>0$ because of the second inequality.

Hence $\displaystyle x<0$.

From first inequality, $\displaystyle 1 < -2x\\\displaystyle x<-\frac{1}{2}$

Therefore $\displaystyle x<-\frac{1}{2}$ is the only solution.

Credit to Zarrax who helped me realise what I had originally missed.

Comment: I got the same solution. I assume that x must not be zero, because that is where the fraction is not defined. Why does it say in the solutions:$(x< -\frac{1}{2}) V (x>0); x<0$ ?

Comment: $1/x < 0$ is relevant here; it forces $x$ to be negative. Note that $-2 < {1 \over x}$ is solved by any $x > 0$.

Comment: @Zarrax. No that inequality is not relevant. All solutions of $x < -\frac{1}{2}$ are already negative.

Comment: @Deepak $-2 < {1 \over x}$ is solved by any $x > 0$, so that inequality would not be enough to get the correct answer. This sort of annoyance is why I suggest squaring both sides in this type of problem.

Comment: @Zarrax. Good point. I missed that. Yes, squaring does seem neater. But one must be careful to exclude redundant roots introduced in squaring. In this case, no redundant roots are introduced, though.

Answer (score 4):

When you have an equation only involving absolute values and other positive quantities, you can square both sides. Sometimes this makes it easier to solve, as in this case.
$$\bigg({x +1 \over x}\bigg)^2 < 1$$
Multiply both sides by $x^2$....

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\left|\frac{x+1}{x}\right|=\left|1+\frac{1}{x}\right|$ and in general
$\left|1+a\right|<1\iff a\in\left(-2,0\right)$. So apply this on
$a=\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

For which $x$ is this fraction defined?

Can we multiply both sides by $|x|$? What will happen with the sign of the inequality?

What are the points of sign-changing of left and right hand sides of the new inequality?

Can you solve it case by case?

Answer (score 1):

Since $|x|\ge 0$, and we may assume $x\neq 0$ for the fraction to be defined, we multiply both sides by $|x|$ to get $$|x+1|<|x|$$
We now complete the problem with geometry, rewriting as $$|x-(-1)|<|x-0|$$
The expression $|x-a|$ measures the distance between $x$ and $a$, so we want all points $x$ that are closer to $-1$ than they are to $0$.  This is exactly all points $x<-0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Since both sides of the inequality are positive,you can get them squared..and solve it like a normal equation..